# Why kernel.controller and AppFiltersListener take too long time

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to improve the project's performance, and discover all request takes 567ms.
Why do those two sections take too long time ??!!

I use symfony2.5 and php5.6

Any ideas, please?

[image]

Comment: Usually this is caused by php waiting for something, e.g. for a database query, network or disk I/O. You can use a full fledged profiler, like blackfire.io or tideways.io to get more detail on which calls take long and why. In any case when we don't know the code, we can't really help and sometimes you can't even clearly tell from the code what is the cause, that's why you should do profiling or some stopwatch calls to see where it gets stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved

1. First of all i installed APC (PHP caching) on my webserver and restart it.
2. Modify my doctrine configuration to use APC.

```
orm:
   metadata_cache_driver: apc
   result_cache_driver: apc
   query_cache_driver: apc
```

3. Modify the service configuration as well.

```
services:
   cache:
       class: Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache
```

The response time was less than I expected.